# Android Studio Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right doesn't work in Windows

Tags: windows, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

The shortcut command suggested by the Android Studio to navigate back/front tab is Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right. But that (Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right) doesn't work in Window. It's changing entire screen to portrait because windows have a feature to rotate the screen in any of the four views with the same commands(Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right). Is there any alternate shortcut command?

1. Android Studio: 3.6.1
2. Kotlin plugin: 1.3.61
3. Android Gradle Plugin: 3.6.1
4. Gradle: 5.6.4

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your hot keys were overwritten by some apps. E.g. Intel Graphics HD, or Geforce Experience... Disable the shortcuts in these apps to make it working again.